# How to use TTask and IXMLHttpRequest correctly?

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to figure out how to use TTask and IXMLHttpRequest together in Delphi 10 Seattle. But my code with TTask doesn't work.

This code work:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  s: string;
begin
  s := 'api request url here'; 
  req := CoXMLHTTP.Create;
  req.open('GET', s, false, EmptyParam, EmptyParam);
  req.send(EmptyParam);
  UpdateRoot(SO(req.responseText));
end;
```

But this code doesn't work, nothing happens after I click the Button1:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  s: string;
  req: IXMLHttpRequest;
  aTask: ITask;
begin
  s := 'api request url here'; 
  aTask := TTask.Create (procedure()
    begin
      req := CoXMLHTTP.Create;
      req.open('GET', s, false, EmptyParam, EmptyParam);
      req.send(EmptyParam);
      UpdateRoot(SO(req.responseText));
    end);
  aTask.Start;
end;
```

How to change second code to running a task in the background? I want use functionality of TTask to prevent the Form1 from locking *(not responding)* while getting API response. I found the example of using TTask [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Using_TTask_from_the_Parallel_Programming_Library):

Comment: you must initialize the COM context to use COM objects in threads, in the main thread this is done automatically for you.In other threads you must call CoInitialize/CoUninitialize yourself

Comment: Also you must take care not to update VCL visual components from within the task as it is not threadsafe (talking about your UpdateRoot procedure)

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42905076/800214)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, whosrdaddy, your solution works great. I changed the code this way and it works as I expected:

```
aTask := TTask.Create (procedure()
        begin
          try
            CoInitialize(nil);
              try
                req := CoXMLHTTP.Create;
                req.open('GET', s, false, EmptyParam, EmptyParam);
                req.send(EmptyParam);
                TThread.Synchronize(nil,
                  procedure
                    begin
                      UpdateRoot(SO(req.responseText));
                    end);
              finally
                CoUninitialize();
              end;
          except
           on E: Exception do
             ShowMessage(E.ToString());
          end;
        end);
      aTask.Start;
```

Comment: Make sure that `req` goes out of scope, or is explicitly set to nil, before `CoUninitialize()` is called. Also, you don't need to synchronize `SO(req.responseText)` only `UpdateRoot()`. Also, `ShowMessage()` is not thread-safe either, so it would need to be synchronized as well, otherwise use `Windows.MessageBox()` instead.